# Debugging 502 Server Error on Debian 7 with Apache PHP

Tags: php, apache, google-compute-engine

I have set up a web server on Google Compute Engine.

I have installed Apache, PHP on it. Sometimes, when i run a file it gives 502 Server Error.

When i refresh the same page, the scripts runs fine.

The error is not constant on a particular page. It just appears on any page and does not appear again when i refresh the same page.

Can anyone please help me which file to look for to check what is causing the error.

I have installed Joomla 3 on the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could start looking into `/var/log/apache2` (if your is the default configuration) for the apache logs. More specifically on `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for the latest errors logs. Perhaps the server is crashing and restarting and then you get this message until it is restarted.